# It is normal when using "LeafletForBlazor" to have an automatic marker appear on the map

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly

After creating the map, when I went to view it, a marker appeared, even though I didn't put it in the code to show one

I've tried to see it on several sites, including the GitHub repository itself, and here. But I didn't find anything.

Comment: Please share the codes or details information about the LeafletForBlazor in your issue.

Comment: I've already talked to the owner of the package,so I don't need this question to be answered